# How to determine the number of input image channels?

Tags: opencv

For reading an image file, I have to use either of

```
Mat img = imread(file,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

or

```
Mat img = imread(file,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

This means I have to know in advance whether the file contains a color or mono image. Isn't there a way to know the number of channels in advance so that I can apply the image read according to the number of channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [imread documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread), you should use `<0 Return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel)`.

In `highui_c.h` there is this definition:

```
CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED  =-1,
```

Oddly CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED is not mentioned in the [imread documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread), but is used in [one of the OpenCV tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html).
This will do what you want:

```
Mat img = imread(file, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

Comment: Mr. B, thanks for the answer. It works. I found that some black and white image returns with 3, img.channel(). That kind images might be defective, not properly converted from color to mono.