# How to determine the number of channels in image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to see the number of channels for thermal images, RGB images, grayscale images and binary images.

So I write this program:

```
import cv2
import numpy

img = cv2.imread("B2DBy.jpg")
print('No of Channel is: ' + str(img.ndim))

cv2.imshow("Channel", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

But it gives the same three channel results for all types of images? I've **[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902726/how-to-determine-the-number-of-input-image-channels)** question but it gives an error:

```
img = cv2.imread("B2DBy.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
NameError: name 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED' is not defined
```

So my question is: Is it is the right way to see the number of channels? Or, somehow, I entered three channel images all the time and thus it gives three channel output?

My inputs:

[image: Thermal Image]

[image: Gray sacle Image]

[image: Binary Image]

[image: RGB Image]

Comment: @HansHirse I've added the input images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct parameter in your `cv2.imread` should be:

```py
img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Let's have a look at your images now. I use [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/)'s `Show Info...` command as well as the following Python code with OpenCV and [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```py
import cv2
from PIL import Image

img_pil = Image.open('path/to/your/image')
print('Pillow: ', img_pil.mode, img_pil.size)

img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print('OpenCV: ', img.shape)
```

#### First image (depth map)

```
Pillow:  RGB (640, 512)
OpenCV:  (512, 640, 3)
```

ImageJ also says, that's a RGB image. So, most likely, your depth map was just saved as a RGB `png`.

#### Second image (dog)

```
Pillow:  RGB (332, 300)
OpenCV:  (300, 332, 3)
```

Interestingly, ImageJ says, that's an grayscale `jpg`! I assume, OpenCV and Pillow just don't support grayscale `jpg`, although there seems to be a [grayscale `jpg` format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008883).

#### Third image (sign)

```
Pillow:  1 (200, 140)
OpenCV:  (140, 200)
```

Both, Pillow and OpenCV say, that's a grayscale image, which is also supported by ImageJ. Furthermore, Pillow uses [mode `'1'`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) here, which is reflected by the dithered look of the image.

#### Fourth image (colours)

```
Pillow:  RGB (500, 333)
OpenCV:  (333, 500, 3)
```

That's just some RGB image; ImageJ also says this.

#### Conclusion

Yes, most likely, most of your images may just be RGB images. Nevertheless, using `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` at least will properly identify grayscale `png` files. It's questionable, if grayscale `jpg` files are properly supported.

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
Pillow:      7.0.0
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If image is grayscale you will need to set a flag, tuple returned contains only number of rows and columns.

So it is a good method to check if loaded image is grayscale or color image.

```
image = cv2.imread('gray.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image.shape
```

If `len(img.shape)` gives you three, third element gives you number of channels.

Comment: But using len(img.shape) also gives 3 (third element) for all input.

Comment: Try setting the Load_image_grayscale flag

Comment: img.shape[2] gives you the number of channels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll work, but documentation says this:
cv.LoadImage(filename, iscolor=flag) with flags given. There's a flag "<0" that stands for "Return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel)".
I would try this:

```
img = cv2.imread("B2DBy.jpg",iscolor=<0)
```

or this

```
img = cv2.imread("B2DBy.jpg",iscolor=CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH)
```

Comment: for the first one, it gives invalid syntax for =< sign & for the second one it gives NameError.

Comment: I'm sorry :( Also, would you mind trying img = cv2.imread("B2DBy.jpg",-1) ?

Comment: I just found out that there's no way in OpenCV to find out if your image is RGB, GreyScale or any other if you don't know it beforehand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122706/detect-color-space-with-opencv
read this for further explanation